# change font size of a variable

Tags: asp.net

I have a Label Control that contains two variables

```
varaiableA="Hello";
variableB="World";

Label.Text= variableA+" "+variableB;
```

I want to have an output of "Hello Word", but the "World" or *variable* must have a smaller font size compared to *variableA*

Comment: Is this [tag:asp-classic] or are you using [tag:asp.net]? Keep in mind they are very different technologies. If you have miss-tagged this question please correct it.

Comment: Good point Lankymart, just noticed the "Label.Text", it's more than likely .NET

Comment: The trick is to realize that variables don't have font sizes. Label controls can have font sizes, and so can `<span>` tags.

Comment: @Lankymart: it has to be ASP.NET - are there controls in Classic ASP?

Answer (score 0):

Are you not able to create a function that wraps a smaller span with a style around the variable of your choice?

E.g.

```
  Function smallFont(str)
      smallFont = "<span style=""font-size:10px"">" & str & "</span>"
  End Function
```

So then you would do:

```
Dim varaiableA : varaiableA = "Hello"
Dim variableB  : variableB = "World"

Response.Write(varaiableA & smallFont(variableB))
```

This example is in ASP VBScript, so may need adjusting if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of the language, you should probably return the variable like so...

```
Label.Text = variableA + ' <span class="smaller-text">' + variableB + '</span>'
```

... or any other tag you are comfortable using and then you can just style it with CSS.